# Parallel API calls to read a row and update it according to result fetched, in mysql, results in a race condtion

Tags: mysql

Application written in **scala on play framework**.

MySql table: The table **example_table** is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
  `itemSetId`    BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `version`      BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `status`       VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `activatedAt`  BIGINT NULL,
  `typeA_id` varchar(36) NULL,
  `typeB_id` varchar(36) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemsetId`, `version`)
);
```

Here *status* can either active or inactive, *typeA_id* and *typeB_id* are UUID strings, *version* is a timestamp.

At a time there should be only one row in the table for a particular *itemsetId* with *status*=active.

Working of the APIs: Both the API does a similar thing for an itemsetID, say 123, except that the API-1 updates the **typeA_id** while API-2 updates the **typeB_id**,

1. Read the row for the latest *version* (timestamp) from the table with itemsetId=123 and status=active.
2. Do some service level logic, and generate a new UUID.
3. Set the *status* of the row fetched in step 1 as **inactive**, create a new row in the table(similar to the row fetched in step 1) except with *status*=**active** and, here one of the API updates the row fetched in step 1 with **typeA_id**=newUUID, while the other API updates **typeB_id**=newUUID.

At a time there should be only one row in the table for a particular *itemsetId* with *status*=active.

The race condition happens when both the APIs are called concurrently. Both the APIs read the latest row for a given itemsetId and with *status*=active. Both does some service level logic. But one of the API updates **typeA_id** and creates a new row with *status*=active, while the other API updates **typeB_id** and creates another new row with *status*=active. Hence we have two rows with *status*=active, when we intended to have one final row with *status*=active and each of the typeA_id and typeB_id updated in the same row. Though we don't care how many rows were created in between, but finally we intended to have one row with both the changes.

What's actually happening:

Either,
Both the APIs are reaching the above step-3 at the same time, hence are creating two rows, with the updates to typeA_id and typeB_id in the separate rows.

Or, one of the API completes step-3 and creates a new row with *status*=active and typeA_id updates, then the other API reaches step-3, inactivates all the rows with status=active(which includes the one created by API-1) and creates a new row with just typeB_id updated.

I can't come up with a specific solution to the problem, please help.

Comment: So you already have a transaction?

Comment: It does seem that if you simply used an autoincrementing id, then this would solve your problem